# Meaning and function of "会" in 我都会把下次学生需要带东西写在黑板上?

Tags: grammar, meaning

“每次下课前，我都**会**把下次学生需要带东西写在黑板上”
*(hsk3 standard course textbook chapter 12, text 4）*

1. What's the meaning and function of ”会“ in this sentence?
2. Can I omit it and still preserve the meaning of the sentence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

“每次下课前，我都把下次学生需要带东西写在黑板上” = Every time right before the dismissal of class, I always write on the blackboard the items that the students need to bring with the next time.

“每次下课前，我都”**会**“把下次学生需要带东西写在黑板上” = Every time right before dismissal of the class, I "**would**" always write on the blackboard the items that the students need to bring with the next time.

**Here, 会 = will**.

While both sentences mean the same, the slight difference is that the sentence with "会" has a stronger sense of "self-motivated willingness" in doing such a routine as opposed to "just (follow the rule) do the job".

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%9C%83#Chinese):

> 4. will; to be likely to; to be sure to
>
>    火車**會**準時到達。／火车**会**准时到达。  ―  Huǒchē huì zhǔnshí dàodá.  ―  The train will arrive on time.
>
>    人人都**會**犯錯。／人人都**会**犯错。  ―  Rénrén dōu huì fàncuò.  ―  Everyone makes mistakes.

If you omit 会, you remove the implication that this *will* happen again in the future:

> 每次下课前，我都⬚把下次学生需要带东西写在黑板上。

This means "I have done so" but does not carry the meaning that "I will continue to do so".

Answer (score 3):

If "会" is omitted in the sentence, it emphasize things already happened in the past (still hints strongly that it will be the same in the future); with "会" added, it emphasize things will be like this in the future.

BTW, you miss a "的" here, "需要带东西" should be "需要带的东西", it's quite important here.

我都会把下次学生需要带东西写在黑板上, literally means: I always write "next time students should bring things" on the blackboard. Most still understand your actual meaning when see it though, because the literal meaning of this sentence is too weird.

Answer (score 0):

每次下课前，我都会把下次学生需要带东西写在黑板上
每次下课前，我都会把下次学生需要带的东西写在黑板上

They are totally different.
每次下课前，我都会把下次学生需要带东西写在黑板上

这句话的意思是，你在黑板上写了一句话，这句话的全文是

下次学生需要带东西

每次下课前，我都会把下次学生需要带的东西写在黑板上
这句话的意思是，你写在黑板上的是一些东西，学生需要携带的。

一个"的"字的省略，意思差太大了。